# How to obtain carrier profile for iOS devices

Tags: ios

I am currently experimenting setting up an MVNO - I have the SIMs provided by my host network (from a reseller) and they work as expected on Android devices, but iOS devices considers my SIMs as the host network's ones, and installs their profile.

The issue is that some features (personal hotspot) are restricted on their profile based on their customer-facing terms and conditions, which do not apply to me as I am billed for data by the megabyte and am free to use it as I wish. Some critical features like VoLTE, WiFi Calling and visual voicemail do not work at all as I can't tell the device to use my servers instead of the host carrier's.

I've tried contacting Apple Developer support who referred me to an irrelevant support article, and there's zero public documentation about this. I've also gotten in touch with *wwwmarcom@apple.com* but have yet to receive any reply and it's been 3 days. The reseller can't help and the host network themselves probably wouldn't care unless this is a million-dollar deal which obviously it isn't (at least not yet).

Comment: If you did open up a DTS ticket, you can reply to it (which reopens it) and tell them their info was bogus (but be sure to detail exactly *why* it was bogus).  That might prompt them to actually do proper research into your issue and give you a better answer.